# How to determine if an NSButton is a checkbox?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nib, nsbutton

In Interface Builder you can set the style of a button to "Check" to turn it into a checkbox, and you can set the style of a button in code using NSButton's `setButtonStyle:` method, but how can I determine at runtime whether a particular `NSButton` is a checkbox (or radio button, or regular push button, etc)?

Part of the project I am working on requires loading views from other bundles and there is special behaviour required for each checkbox (these bundles are from 3rd parties).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a foolproof way to do this. You can check the bezelStyle, and for a checkbox that logs 2 (NSRegularSquareBezelStyle). I don't know if there are other buttons that have the NSRegularSquareBezelStyle, that are not check boxes.  You'll probably have to experiment to find this out.

After Edit : I did find one other button that logs 2 for bezelStyle (the bevel button), but you can log [button.cell showsStateBy], and the check box was the only one I found that logs 1.

Comment: Good effort! It doesn't sound foolproof as you say but it's a good start at least.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but in case an enterprising young Googler ends up here, I thought I may mention some stuff I've found to help narrow down the list of types. `NSButtonCell` has a method called `-imageDimsWhenDisabled`. It only returns `NO` for the `NSSwitchButton` ( checkbox) and `NSRadioButton` button types. Therefore, if we check that, along with the `-bezelStyle` and `-showsStateBy`/`-highlightsBy` tricks, the list of possible button types decreases quite a bit. Also, `-imagePosition` generally returns `NSImageLeft` for checkboxes and radio buttons. It's not 100%, but it helps.